# Adaptive Cards Templating in MS Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I can't seem to get this to work.  If I send the following adaptive card payload to MS Teams:

```
{
  "$schema" : "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
  "version" : "1.3",
  "type" : "AdaptiveCard",
  "body" : [ {
    "type" : "Container",
    "style" : "emphasis",
    "items" : [ {
      "type" : "Input.Text",
      "value" : "${form.name}",
      "id" : "name",
      "label" : "Name"
    } ]
  } ],
  "$data" : {
    "form" : {
      "name" : "geoff hurst"
    },
  }
}
```

I get a response in Teams like this:

[image: Result in teams]

I would have thought that the template should be expanded on the client-side, but this doesn't seem to happen.  Have I misunderstood?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in simple terms, Teams doesn't have an ability to *render* templates (basically that would mean taking the card template and the data payload and combining them together) - it can only accept the final version of the card.

As a result, if you're wanting to use templates, then you need to implement the data + template capability your side, to send the *final* card payload down to Teams. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/templating/) for examples on how to do this in js or dotnet. Truth be told, if you're in js (e.g. Node), Templating is not much more than string replacement, and if you're in dotnet (e.g. C#) there's a strongly-typed Adaptive Card library you might want to rather use anyway, in which case you're combining the "template" and the "data" already inside your code.

I think probably the best use of templating would be if you're receiving a template from some kind of "template repository", but I don't think there's really practically any such thing yet for Teams.

Answer (score 0):

The method you are trying to use will not allow you to use dynamic data, I prefer you use data as a separate object and use Templating SDKs.

Please have a look at this [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/0c55dc7f9d6aab6b93d625c6edd466f4b81cf84b/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/57.teams-conversation-bot/Bots/TeamsConversationBot.cs#L265-L279) on how to use template :

```
var templateJSON = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(".", "CardPath"));
AdaptiveCardTemplate template = new AdaptiveCardTemplate(templateJSON);
var memberData = new
{
    userName = member.Name,
    userUPN = member.UserPrincipalName,
    userAAD = member.AadObjectId
};
string cardJSON = template.Expand(memberData);
var adaptiveCardAttachment = new Attachment
{
    ContentType = "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
    Content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(cardJSON),
};
await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Attachment(adaptiveCardAttachment), cancellationToken);
```

In the above snippet as you can see, we need to create a model having the fields that we are using in the card.

In your case you need to create a object having the property as form -> name

```
var formData = new
{
    form = new
    {
        name = "Testing"
    }
};
```

after that use the expand method and the rest code would be same.

Comment: Ok, agreed.  You're right, although according to this page:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/templating/ there are multiple, good reasons why you'd want to template on the client-side.   The fact that Teams implements Adaptive cards but not the template language seems like a bug to me.